# Change in observable collection Item not reflecting in datagrid

Tags: wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

I'm using observable collection as data source for a datagrid in WPF.

There are around 20 columns in my datagrid.

If I make any change the value of a particular cell,I'm not able to see the same reflected in UI.Cell shows the same old value.If I click on that cell latest value appears.

I will explain this with an example.
Say I have two properties in an observable collection Name and Age.
IF I add some 4 or 5 columns to the observable collection from viewmodel,the same is getting displayed in UI.If I change the value of Age in a particular row from viewmodel the latest value is not visible in grid.Latest value appears when  I click on that cell.

Could anyone tell what needs to be done to get the changes reflected in UI?

Comment: Is underlying source class implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface?

Answer (score 7):

ObservableCollection inherits INotifyCollectionChanged, so that the view can update when elements are added or removed, and INotifyPropertyChanged, so that the view can update if the whole list is refreshed (set).

However, once you have an item from that observable collection in a collection container (like a data grid) the data context for that row becomes the source object (that is, the object contained within the observable collection). If this source object does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged, changes to its data will not propagate to the UI.

Basically, whatever objects your ObservableCollection is aggregating also need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.